# Looking For an App to Manage Cloud Services

Tags: cloud, dropbox

Is there any apps in Ubuntu that can manage cloud services? (Sky Drive - Google Drive - Drop Box and ....)
something like ES File Manager In Android that can Add and manage many cloud services.
Of course i didn’t found any apps for windows that can manage them together in one.
If there is any in Ubuntu let me know...
thanks

Comment: This doesn't really exist in Windows, never mind linux. There are working clients for all 3 but nothing integrated...

Comment: You might be interested in [Joli Cloud](https://www.jolicloud.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a single application, however, integration with the file-manager can be very tight and work well.

## Dropbox

The official Dropbox client transparently syncs all your files and integrates with Nautilus. Moreover, you can even add or edit the files by any other mean (including the terminal) and it will still work.

## Google Drive

Google Drive can be mounted similarly to an external drive, thus allowing seamless access through Nautilus and other software. There is a detailed [blog article](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/mount-google-drive-in-linux-with-google.html) about this.

Here is a small summary: the software is called `google-drive-ocamlfuse` and can be installed with a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

It must be started a first time to authorize it to access your account:

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

Then you can create a folder to act as the mount point and start accessing Google Drive:

```
mkdir ~/gdrive
google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/gdrive
```

## OneDrive (formerly SkyDrive)

There is a similar software for OneDrive, called OneDrive-D. Again, there is a [neat blog article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/one-drive-ubuntu-integration) about it, and here's a quick summary.

You have to download the software from GitHub and unzip it:

```
wget https://github.com/xybu92/onedrive-d/archive/master.zip -O onedrived.zip
unzip onedrived.zip && rm onedrived.zip
```

Then you can start the installation script:

```
cd onedrive-d-master/
sudo ./inst install
```

If you don't see the configuration window, run `onedrive-prefs`. To launch the app after a reboot, you need to run `onedrive-d`.

Comment: Could you edit in the commands needed to get Google Drive Ocamlfuse and OneDrive-D?

Comment: Mmm yes, I could... I didn't actually think it was necessary. The questions asks «Is there any apps ...», so the answer should be of the "yes/no" type. Do you think I should include the commands as well?

Comment: Well otherwise it is looking like a link only answer... At least for the "blog article" one?

Comment: I improved it. I'd like to hear your feedback. :)